# How can I use Q objects on Two Dynamic Search Forms in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django project where I want to search profile records for those that are resident in a particular country and state.

In this project I would be collecting data of people from different countries and their respective states, so I want a situation where I can have two Search Forms for Country and State.

The form should be able to allow me select list of countries in the Profile Model while the state form should be able to allow me type and search for a state in the selected country.

The result should be a list of persons in the selected Country and searched state.Please understand that I decided to go with Q objects because I learn that it makes queries efficient.

Here are my model code:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    applicant = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    othernames = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER, blank=True, null=True)
    nation = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=NATION, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='avatar.jpg', upload_to ='profile_images')
```

Here is my search form code:

```
class Applicant_Search_Form(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ['nation', 'state']
```

Here is my views code:

```
def SearchApplicants(request):

form = Applicant_Search_Form(request.GET or None)

if form:
    list_submited = Q(nation__icontains = form['nation'].value()) & Q(state__icontains = form['state'].value())

else:
    list_submited = Profile.objects.all()

paginator = Paginator(list_submited, 5)
page = request.GET.get('page')
paged_listApps = paginator.get_page(page)

context = {
'list_applicants':paged_listApps,
'form':form,


}

return render(request, 'user/list_applicants.html',context)
```

I have tried running the above code but I am have a TypeError which says 'Q' object is not subscriptable.

Someone should kindly help with how to solve this problem and possibly the best approach to this kind of search.Thank in anticipation to your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should filter the `Profile.objects.all()` queryset, so:

```
def SearchApplicants(request):
    form = Applicant_Search_Form(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        list_submited = Profile.objects.filter(
            nation__icontains=form.cleaned_data['nation'],
            state__icontains=form.cleaned_data['state']
        )
    else:
        list_submited = Profile.objects.all()
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: Functions are normally written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, therefore it is
> advisable to rename your function to `search_applicants`, not <s>`SearchApplicants`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Forms in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`Applicant_Search_Form`</s> to `ApplicantSearchForm`.